# Postgres case sensitivity : Implications of Lower()

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, case-sensitive

I have run into the issue of case sensitive searching in postgres, and have started to deal with this by using LOWER on each side of every WHERE test.

So far so good.  However, I understand that in order to make use of indexes, they should be created use LOWER too, which makes sense.

However, what of the PK?  presumably these are not going to be effective because it does not seem possible to create a PK using a function on the chosen PK field.  Isnt this a concern for any filtering or joining which is done on PKs?

Is there a way of working around this ?

Comment: Do you *really* need a character column as a PK? A workaraound is a serial as surrogate PK (and maybe a unique constraint on the character column)

Comment: It is a legacy database whose current model is used by a number of products.  Making extensive changes will incur a disproportionate amount of regression testing which I am hoping to minimise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still create a functional index on PK (even consisting of many columns):

```
CREATE TABLE test(a text, b text, c text, d text, primary key (a,b,c));
CREATE INDEX ON test (lower(a), lower(b), lower(c));
```

Though, it sounds like there is need for some data improvement operations to be done if you are experiencing this kind of behaviour almost everywhere in your database (like store everything in lower case).

Comment: I would expect the creation of a PK to create an index in its own right. That would mean there would be an index on the fundamental data, and one on the LOWERcase data.  How do we know which one the query plan will use ?

Comment: Depending on your WHERE clause the optimizer will choose a suitable plan. Try it yourself with `EXPLAIN` keyword placed before SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at that.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some thoughts on this subjects.

First, you *could* add a constraint for any column requiring that the data stored be lower case.  That would solve the problem inside the database.

Second, you could use a trigger to convert any value to lower case.

Third, you can use `ilike`.  This can make use of indexes for case-insensitive searches.

And fourth, if all your primary keys are synthetic numeric primary keys, then you don't need to worry about case sensitivity.